# Can't build HPX with CMake on Windows - found [Boost] suitable version "1.75.0", minimum required is "1.61"

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake, hpx

I'm trying to build HPX with CMake on Windows 10 (the end game is to build OpenCV with MSVC).
I have downloaded Boost 1.75.0, ran `bootstrap.bat` then `b2.exe` from an admin CMD. I then added the path to the boost folder to PATH variable.
Next I opened CMake and tried to build HPX 1.3.0 and got the following error:

```
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1326 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1935 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/HPX_SetupBoost.cmake:75 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:1576 (include)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1204 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1326 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1935 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/HPX_SetupBoost.cmake:75 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:1576 (include)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1204 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1326 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1935 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/HPX_SetupBoost.cmake:75 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:1576 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem program_options system) (found
  suitable version "1.75.0", minimum required is "1.61")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2193 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/HPX_SetupBoost.cmake:75 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:1576 (include)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like CMake found the Boost header files but not the Boost binaries. I would try explicitly setting the `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` CMake variables pointing to the corresponding directories. See also https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html for more CMake variables you could set.

Note also, that the warnings issued in your logs are benign and caused by your CMake version being older than Boost V1.75.